# PDF stream info

Tags: python, pdf, hex

I was working on an online challenge and ended up with a PDF stream that I attempted to decode in python. I ended up with this:

[image: picture]

The YYY and up arrow look familiar from some kind of file-- do you guys know what it is? Also, what could the numbers mean? (I decoded the TJ as hex since is was in <>)

I also have the Tm coordinates if that would help.

Comment: By *"I decoded the TJ as hex since is was in <>"* do you say that your screen shot is the decoded hex content of the **TJ** operator argument string? In that case you should consider using the PDF font actave at the time of that **TJ** operation.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So where would I go about finding such info? It's special elite -- I downloaded tff file for that but can't seem to find out how to view the hex codes

Comment: nvm i just guessed the offset. thanks!

Comment: You have to look at the corresponding font dictionary to try and find the encoding used.

Comment: This says it maps normally, but it does not. In the pdf it says special elite-reuglar with identity-h mappings. I had to shift all the character 59 places and now have english but a few chars seem off. http://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-special-elite-f84466.htm

Comment: "identity-h" does not imply "shift all the character 59 places" but "inspect the font program". The 59 shift is there often but it is not required. Alternatively also look for the **ToUnicode** map.